# Javascript time detection for change background color for day/night

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if someone knows what i am doing wrong. Maybe it isn't possible at all.

```
<script>
 var daynight = document.querySelector('header');
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    if (hours >= 6 && hours < 14){
        console.log(avond);
        daynight.classList.add('nacht');
    }
    if(hours < 6 || hours >= 14){
            console.log(dag);
            daynight.classList.remove('nacht');
    } 
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: all hours greater than 14 are also greater than 6.

Comment: Ummm...I think you meant to use `<script>` tags not `<code>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5xd9nnb/) check out this answer

```
var daynight = document.querySelector('header');
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    if (hours < 6 || hours >= 14){
        console.log('night');
        daynight.classList.add('nacht');
    }
    if(hours >= 6 && hours < 14){
        console.log('day');
        daynight.classList.remove('nacht');
    }
```

Comment: @GideondeVries great! be sure to mark it down as answered

Comment: where can i do that?I am new at stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Are `avond` and `dag` defined variables? If not you need to add quotes around them. If the issue persists afterwards, let us know if there is any error in the console window.

As for the second if: You should definitely use an `else` or a second condition there, as this code will always be executed if the top is executed too (if `hours >= 14` evaluates `true` so does `hours >=6`, it should be `hours >= 6 && hours < 14` and `hours < 6 || hours >= 14`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, bud you mean   hours >= 6&& hours <14 and <6 && hours >=14 ? because i dont understand the ||.

Comment: @GideondeVries it's a logical OR. `hours` can't be smaller than 6 AND bigger or equal to 14 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're declare 'avond' and 'dag' outside your posted code snippet.

```
var daynight = document.querySelector('header');
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    if (hours >= 14){
        //Add night logic here
    }
    else if(hours >= 6){ //Important to add 'ELSE' here to prevent it from always firing when first condition is met (like Mathletics said in comment)
            console.log(dag);
            daynight.classList.remove('nacht');
    }
```